# Possible to have a table with variable columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

It might be a stupid question, but here goes:

Is it possible to make a dynamic table that's able to contain rows with variable number of columns and custom column names?

I have glanced over EAV-modelling, but it seems heavy. A real life example could be this:

Let's say I have a register with customers. But each customer might have different information to be entered. And depending on what you want to enter, it should be reflected in the database. (I.E. every customer has different columns)

Is this impossible/probable?

**Update:**

The standard approach (i.e. *having a table with all needed columns and saving information only into columns that make sense for a particular customer while setting the remaining ones to NULL*) doesn't work for me because what I want can't use 'fixed' column names. Example one customer might want CVR-number and another might want their phonenumber as a reference number. And a third might want some completely different information. So to avoid having a table containing 500 columns, I have now thought of making an extra table containing rows of column-data. Like so: Id, Name, Value, CustomerId. So when I want information for a customer, all I have to do is to iterate through this table with a specific customer Id.

**my own edit!:**

Sorry for troubling you with this simple SQL-issue! :-) Have a nice day...

Comment: I think it's not possible. A suggestion could be: save variable user data in a specific format (XML for example) in a db field and decode data when you retrieve it from db. I don't know if mine could be an answer.. at this time I prefer leaving it as a comment...

Comment: That's called the Entity-Attribute-Value data model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model and I generally avoid it because of the complexity required in your SQL queries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could model this as a one-to-many relationship between a Customer and a CustomerAttributes table. Something like:

```
**Customer table**
CustomerId
LastName
FirstName
...

**CustomerAttributes table**
CustomerId
AttributeName
AttributeValue
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Sql-Server. As Marco says, you can store each customer's data in xml.

If all the columns are known ahead of time and some customers use one set and other customers use a different set, then sub-tables with each set of columns is the normal approach.

If the columns are not known ahead of time, then how would the data even be used? No code or reports could refer to it. Perhaps it should be stored unstructured in a general purpose 'Notes' field.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible in standard relational databases, but you can take a look at schema-less databases called 'No-SQL' like [MongoDB](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/119945109/why-schemaless)