# Uploading Data from Excel to Database C#

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, upload

I have a small problem. Once I read the data from the excel file into a Data table variable, I need to upload it into a table in the database. But the number of columns in the excel file is not fixed. Hence I need to create a table each time while uploading. I want to call a stored procedure to create the table. For this, I pass the first row(which contains the column names for creating the table) to the stored procedure. How do I do it considering that the number of columns is unknown? I couldn't pass it as an array as stored procedure doesn't accept arrays. Please help.

Comment: One common solution is to save the data table as an XML in the DB

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305518/possible-to-have-a-table-with-variable-columns

Answer (score 0):

[T-SQL: Parse a delimited string](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2006/02/03/T-SQL-Parse-a-delimited-string) is what you are looking for.

Quote:

> I most commonly use this chunk of code when I need to pass an array from an application into a SQL Stored Procedure.